# PowerShell Advanced Function get current ParameterSetName

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

In C# you can get the current `ParameterSetName` in the `ProcessRecord` override of a PowerShell `Cmdlet` with code like this:

```
 switch (ParameterSetName)
 {
      case FromUriParamSetName:
           loadFromUri();
           break;

      case FromFileParamSetName:
           loadFromFile();
           break;
 }
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the value for `ParameterSetName` in a script cmdlet (Advanced Function).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a way to expand this awesome answer:

```
switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    "FromFile_ParamSet" {
    }
    "FromUri_ParamSet" {
    }
    "__AllParameterSets" { 
    }
}
```

The `__AllparameterSets` is the default option in PS

Answer (score 20):

Use `$PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName`:

```
switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    "FromFile_ParamSet" {

    }
    "FromUri_ParamSet" {

    }
}
```